# MacBook Pro Big Sur Disk Space Not Properly Allocated

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-space

When I list my available Disk Space, I see that I should have around 466Gi available to me.  However, only ~23Gi is actually available.

```
df -h
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
...
/dev/disk1s1    466Gi   21Gi   33Mi   100%  553789 4881899091    0%   /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1
```

*FULL OUTPUT AT THE TIME*
[image: Full Output At The Time This Happened]

[image: Image showing there should be 499.96GB available]

Why is this the case and what is the best way to fully allocate the Available space?

Comment: Do you have Time Machine enabled?

Comment: No I don't.  Interestingly, I removed a directory that houses a lot of files, and now 80Gi of the 500Gi is allocatable.  ie- By removing that directory, instead of 23Gi of Allocatable space I now have 80Gi of Allocatable space.  I don't understand that.

Comment: Your edited output from df(1) only shows a mounted snapshot volume.  You are not looking at the actual storage.  Don't edit for what you think people need to see, post the complete output.

Comment: Ok @MarcWilson I added a Screenshot I had taken at the time this happened shortly before deciding to join this forum and ask about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I list my available Disk Space, I see that I should have around
> 466Gi available to me.

I'm not sure where you are getting this from.

According to the full `df -h` output, you have `435` out of `466` GB used on your `Data` volume, and most of the remainder of the space is taken up by the system. You should only be seeing 2.5GB free right now, which is well below the recommended 10% and puts you in danger of running out of space due to temporary files or VM swapouts. Sounds like you need to delete some of your 435 GB ASAP.

Comment: Ohhh I see-- I was looking at the wrong Volume and didn't notice the /Data Volume as the culprit.  I will need to read about the mounted snapshot Volume I mistakenly looked at